# Am I understanding dual mode operation of an OS correctly?

Tags: operating-system

I'm trying to understand what dual mode operation of an operating system is. What I've picked up from various sources is that it is a way of the system to protect itself and other components from basic misuse from the user.

(I assume --since I vaguely saw something about a mode bit) Every process is assigned a mode bit to differentiate between user mode and kernel mode processes. The mode bit is stored in the process control block.

So it's only just a method of telling which process has been initiated by the user and which by the OS; to grant certain privileges? (why is it called kernel mode and not OS mode)?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good forum for this question, you should probably ask it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no per process mode bit. The Processor (CPU) has two modes (more than two, but assume it's just 2 for this discussion) - User mode and Privilege mode. Processor executes User space processes in User mode. This is basically to ensure that user space processes do not have more control than necessary (hence prevents malicious users from messing with the system's hardware). Now, when the user process has to make use of the hardware (for instance, File system or IO), it has to request the Kernel to do that on its behalf. It does so using a system call, which internally changes the CPU mode to privileged, hence providing the system call code full access to the system.

Comment: You say there are more than two nodes. Can you explain what those other modes are?

Comment: By "node" I meant "mode".

Comment: There's the concept of CPU rings. Intel x86 has 4 rings typically. 3 for user space, 0 for Kernel. In case of Virtualization 0 for Hypervisor, 1/2 for Guest OS kernel, 3 for Applications. Actually it is a little more complex than that in case of Virtualization. Here's a link that should clarify that: https://itechthoughts.wordpress.com/tag/protection-rings/

Answer (score 0):

Dual-Mode Operation ,it allows OS to protect itself and other system components
there is some thing called Mode bit provided by the hardware, it Provides ability to distinguish when system is running user code or kernel code :)